# Retrieve Birthdays from Facebook, Store and Pop Up to User On that Date

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

My windows phone 8 Apps requires user to export birthdays from Facebook, store the birthday date and then show a pop up or a reminder to the user on that specific date and time.
I just wanted an idea on how to acheieve the same, and any way we can store the data retrieved in the App, which can be visible to the user as well.
Is this possible. Any guidance or code snippets on the same would be great and appreciated.
Awaiting Response.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Anyone any help on the same, please?.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? You can fetch the birthdays using FB API, save the data in the phone storage, what so you need?

Comment: Like can we save the data retrieved in the Contacts section. Also I wanted to know how is the data retireved exactly. All the birth dates of your friends get imported when you query using FQL. Also how to send the notification to the user on that scheduled time. Sorry I am new to using facebook sdk hence these questions.